# C# string.Format alignment issue

Tags: c#, richtextbox, string.format

I have a problem with the alignment of a few names (changed for this question).

[image: program code to display the names in a richtextbox]

with this code I display the names in a richtextbox where it should be in one row with the "Spalte:" after the Names...but it doesn't. Can anybody help me please?

(only the first for-loop is necessary for my question, the next one does another job)

I added a pic what it looks like and how it should be looking. I know I can do it like its in the commented area (doesn't work in every case), but I need to change the code for a few other things so this needs to work....

Here is what I have:

[image: how it looks like now]

And here is what I want:

[image: and how it should look like]

Thanks for helping me :D

Comment: use a fixed-width font. the current font in the text box is a proportional font. and please include code as text, not as a picture.

Comment: Isn't this because you are not using a monospace font like Consolas or Courier New? This causes the alignment issue. You need to create a font and pass it into the control.

Comment: You'll have to use a fixed-pitch font to get those strings to align.  Or use a tab ("\t") between the two strings, set the tab stop with the SelectionTabs property.  Given that it is unlikely that you want the user to actually edit this text, you'd surely ought to consider a ListView with View = Details.  Or DataGridView if editing is desirable.  Either control aligns text by design.

Comment: Please don't post images of your code or data. It makes it much harder for us to help you, and that means you're less likely to get a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have four options:

1. Change the code for the `RichTextBox` to use a fixed-width font. Most fonts have variable widths for each character, meaning you can't line things up neatly based on spacing alone.
2. Use tabs instead of spaces for the layout (and make sure the tab size is large enough to account for variances in your text).
3. Use a grid control of some type (`DataGrid`, `GridView`, etc)
4. Use a custom control for each row with labels at specific places (and either calculate positions yourself to place them on the form or use something like a `FlowLayoutPanel`).